# How to validate that xml attributes should not have time zone information using Schematron?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schematron

How do I validate that all 'signedWhen' xml attributes should not have time zone information using Schematron?  I am using the .NET implementation that uses XPath 1.0.

**Given source XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyData versionDate="2010-12-09" dataBeginDate="2012-03-01" dataEndDate="2012-03-10" extractedWhen="2012-03-09T10:08:40">
  <Site Site_key="999">
    <SitePatient Patient_key="1">
    <txt_Surname value="TEST" signedWhen="2012-03-08T22:02:39" signedWho="SomeName"/>
    <txt_GivenNames value="PATIENT" signedWhen="2012-03-08T22:02:39" signedWho="SomeName"/>
    <dat_BirthDate value="2010-06-15" signedWhen="2012-03-08T22:02:39" signedWho="SomeName"/>
    <sel_Status value="Enrolled" signedWhen="2012-03-08T22:02:39" signedWho="SomeName"/>
    <dat_StatusDate value="2012-03-05-05:00" signedWhen="2012-03-08T22:02:39" signedWho="SomeName"/>
    </SitePatient>
  </Site>
</MyData>
```

**Using this Schematron rule in the XSD file:**

```
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
  <sch:pattern name="All signedWhen TimeZone constraints">
  <sch:rule context="*[@signedWhen]">
  <sch:assert test="(substring(@signedWhen,11,12) != '-') and (substring(@signedWhen,11,12) != '+') and (substring(@signedWhen,11,12) != 'Z')">
       <name/> must not include TimeZone information
    </sch:assert>
  </sch:rule>
  </sch:pattern> 
</xs:appinfo>  
</xs:annotation>
```

**Gives these incorrect results**

It should not return any results as there is no time zone information.

```
NMatrix.Schematron.ValidationException: Results from Schematron validation:
Results from Schematron validation
From pattern "All signedWhen TimeZone constraints"
Assert fails: txt_Surname must not include TimeZone information
At: /MyData[1]/Site[1]/SitePatient[1]/txt_Surname[1]
    <txt_Surname value="TEST" signedWhen="2012-03-08T22:02:39" signedWho="SomeName">...</txt_Surname>
    (Line: 5, Column: 6)
Assert fails: txt_GivenNames must not include TimeZone information
At: /MyData[1]/Site[1]/SitePatient[1]/txt_GivenNames[1]
    <txt_GivenNames value="PATIENT" signedWhen="2012-03-08T22:02:39" signedWho="SomeName">...</txt_GivenNames>
    (Line: 6, Column: 6)
Assert fails: dat_BirthDate must not include TimeZone information
At: /MyData[1]/Site[1]/SitePatient[1]/dat_BirthDate[1]
    <dat_BirthDate value="2010-06-15" signedWhen="2012-03-08T22:02:39" signedWho="SomeName">...</dat_BirthDate>
    (Line: 7, Column: 6)
Assert fails: sel_Status must not include TimeZone information
At: /MyData[1]/Site[1]/SitePatient[1]/sel_Status[1]
    <sel_Status value="Enrolled" signedWhen="2012-03-08T22:02:39" signedWho="SomeName">...</sel_Status>
    (Line: 8, Column: 6)
Assert fails: dat_StatusDate must not include TimeZone information
At: /MyData[1]/Site[1]/SitePatient[1]/dat_StatusDate[1]
    <dat_StatusDate value="2012-03-05-05:00" signedWhen="2012-03-08T22:02:39" signedWho="SomeName">...</dat_StatusDate>
    (Line: 9, Column: 6)
```

**EDIT 1:**

I figured it out.  I was not using the XPath 1.0 function "substring" correctly in my tests.

```
<sch:assert test="(substring(@signedWhen, 11, 1) != '-') and (substring(@signedWhen, 11, 1) != '+') and (substring(@signedWhen, 11, 1) != 'Z')">
```

**EDIT 2:**
W3schools defintion of xs:date and xs:dateTime did not mention the possibility of the optionally negative signed year.  So my code above would not work, see the answer selected below.

**EDIT 3:**
Well the schema I am using (xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ) does not accept a negative signed year - and declares it invalid.  But to be safe I will use this code from now on:

```
<sch:assert test="not ( (contains(substring(@signedWhen, 11, 2), '-')) or (contains(@signedWhen, '+')) or (contains(@signedWhen, 'Z')) )">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you want to handle date or datetime, but when I see your code, maybe both. Your code won't work in some specific cases.

Given the [dateTime specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-lexical-representation) :

> The ·lexical space· of dateTime consists of finite-length sequences of
>   characters of the form: '-'? yyyy '-' mm '-' dd 'T' hh ':' mm ':' ss
>   ('.' s+)? (zzzzzz)?, where ...

You can read further for details. The `(zzz)?` part is the timezone and is as follow (same source) :

> The lexical representation of a timezone is a string of the form:
>   (('+' | '-') hh ':' mm) | 'Z', where...

So your code won't work for date or dateTime like : `-2010-03-08Z` or `2010-03-08T12:01:02.2Z`, for example.

This one should be more generic (and XPath 1.0) :

```
test="not(
            contains(@signedWhen,'+') 
            or contains(@signedWhen,'Z') 
            or (contains(@signedWhen, 'T') 
                 and contains(substring-after(@signedWhen ,':'),'-'))
            or (not(contains(@signedWhen,'T')) and contains(@signedWhen,':'))
            )"
```

Comment: My code should work for your one example "2010-03-08T..", but you are right it won't work for "-2010-03-08Z" I did not realize that was possible, but I was only checking xs:Date at this point, but it makes sense to extend it to xs:dateTime like you have for in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I based my code on xs:date for "http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp" which says the '+' and '-' must be after the date and same with 'T' so if this is true my code would be 100% correct for xs:date - AFAIK.  Also looking further down the page at xs:dateTime my code would also be 100% compatible...?

Comment: For `dateTime`, the timezone is at the end, so it's not at the 11th place in the string representation. Concerning the first "-", it concerns only BC dates and not timezone. I think the w3school page you mention forgot this point about the first "-" (BC dates). For any doubt, I prefer having a look to w3c rec (the link above for dateTime).